# Deleting pictures based on dimensions with PowerShell

Tags: image, powershell, metadata, delete-file

I would like to delete all VERTICAL and SMALL pictures from a certain folder.

I have a folder that I do not want the vertical pictures or pictures with dimensions less than 600 x 600 pixels. I believe that PowerShell is the best thing to use since I cannot get Python to work on my computer.

I am doing this because I do not want to manually delete the vertical/small pictures from my folder each day. (It gets new ones every day)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my code :

```
cd C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Test

$c = 5
Function Get-FileMetaData {

    Param([string[]]$folder)
    foreach($sFolder in $folder) {
        $a = 0
        $b = 1

        $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)

        foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) {

            $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT
            for ($a ; $a -le 266; $a++) {
                if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) {

                    $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) =
                    $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) }
                    $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash

                    if ($($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) -eq "Height") {
                        Write-Host $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) =====
                        $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
                    }

                    if ($($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) -eq "Width") {
                        Write-Host $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) =====
                        $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
                    }

                    if ($($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) -eq "Name") {
                        Write-Host $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a)) =====
                        $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
                    }

                    $b++
                    $hash.clear()

                } #end if
            } #end for
        Write-Host $a
        $a=0
        $FileMetaData
        } #end foreach $file
    $c++
    Write-Host c = $c
    } #end foreach $sfolder
} #end Get-FileMetaData

Write-Host c = $c

$h = Get-FileMetaData C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Test | select Height
$w = Get-FileMetaData C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Test | select Width
$n = Get-FileMetaData C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Test | select Name

$h
Write-Host w = $w
Write-Host name = $n

$SpecChars = '!', "{", "}", '"', 'Â£', '$', '%', '&', '^', '*', '(', ')', '@', '=', '+', 'Â¬', '`', '\', '<', '>', '?', '/', ':', ';', '#', '~', "'", '-', "Name", "N", "a", "m", "e", ' '
$remspecchars = [string]::join('|', ($SpecChars | % {[regex]::escape($_)}))


if (($h) -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1' -gt ($w) -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1') {

        Write-Host "VERTICAL"

        Write-Host name = $n

        $d = $n -replace $remspecchars, ""
        $d.split()
        Write-Host $d
        $tally = 0
        while($tally -ne $d.Count) {
            del $d[$tally]
            $tally++
        }


        $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }

Write-Host "Finished"
```

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here is my code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15ToJa5Sa4cdWlXMllwcDlza0E

Comment: Please include all vital information for your question in your question. If external resources disappear (for whatever reason) your question will become useless to everyone else.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$folder = 'C:\temp\Pictures\'

$image = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile

$pictures = Get-ChildItem $folder *.jpg | ForEach-Object {
    $image.LoadFile($_.fullname)
    $size = $image.Width.ToString() + 'x' + $image.Height.ToString()

    $orientation = $image.Properties | ? {$_.name -eq 'Orientation'} | % {$_.value}
    if ($orientation -eq 6) {
        $rotated = $true
    } else {
        $rotated = $false
    }

    $heightGtWidth = if ([int]$image.Height.ToString() -gt [int]$image.Width.ToString()) {
        $true
    } else {
        $false
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Fullname = $_.FullName
        Size = $size
        Rotated = $rotated
        HeightGtWidth = $heightGtWidth
    }
}

$pictures
```

Comment: This would be better with some explanation of what you've done differently and why, so that the asker and other readers can better understand it.

Comment: Sorry but what I am looking for is to delete pictures that are either vertical or have dimensions less than 600 x 600 pixels

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just had to tweak it a little but you did most of the work.